# d3.timeMonth on axis is showing every date, instead of every month

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am newish to D3, and I've been trying to troubleshoot this issue for a few days now without luck. I'm not sure what to try next.

I have a JSON dataset with daily data, and I'm attempting to make a bar chart with one bar per day. That's all good. However, I'm having trouble with the `x`-axis. I'd like the `x`-axis to have ticks and labels only at the first of each month. It's as if `d3.timeMonth` thinks every data point is a new month:

[image]

I've set up the `x`-axis as `scaleBand`, because every time I tried to set it up as `scaleTime`, the bars displayed as huge overlapping bars. However, just before I set up the `x`-axis, I've printed my data to the console log, and it looks correctly formatted as Dates.

```js
const data = [
  {
    date_facet: '2020-08-31',
    published: 2,
    not_published: 0,
  },
  {
    date_facet: '2020-09-01',
    published: 0,
    not_published: 0,
  },
  {
    date_facet: '2020-09-02',
    published: 1,
    not_published: 0,
  },
  {
    date_facet: '2020-09-03',
    published: 1,
    not_published: 0,
  },
  {
    date_facet: '2020-09-04',
    published: 0,
    not_published: 0,
  },
  {
    date_facet: '2020-09-05',
    published: 0,
    not_published: 0,
  },
];

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 80,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 350 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#graph")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("viewBox", '0 0 450 350')
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// parse the date / time
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

// format the data
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date_facet = parseTime(d.date_facet);
  d.published = +d.published;
});

// order the data
data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a["date_facet"] - b["date_facet"];
})

// X axis
var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, width])
  .domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.date_facet;
  }))
  .padding(0.2);

// Y axis
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0])
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return Math.max(d.published);
  }) + 4]);

// Add X axis, ticks and labels
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis-minor")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
    .ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1))
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b")))
  .selectAll("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("dx", "-.8em")
  .attr("dy", ".15em")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-45)");


svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

// Bars
svg.selectAll("mybar")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.date_facet);
  })
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.published);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.published);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use `scaleBand`, all values are considered categorical. What I mean by that is that they're like labels, like "ball", "orange", "circle". Just terms, completely unrelated to each other. This contrasts with time or numbers, where you can say one value is bigger than the other, or one is closer to A than to B.

Change the values to `scaleTime` instead:

```js
const data = [
  {
    date_facet: '2020-08-31',
    published: 2,
    not_published: 0,
  },
  {
    date_facet: '2020-09-01',
    published: 0,
    not_published: 0,
  },
  {
    date_facet: '2020-09-02',
    published: 1,
    not_published: 0,
  },
  {
    date_facet: '2020-09-03',
    published: 1,
    not_published: 0,
  },
  {
    date_facet: '2020-09-04',
    published: 0,
    not_published: 0,
  },
  {
    date_facet: '2020-09-05',
    published: 0,
    not_published: 0,
  },
];

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 80,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 350 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#graph")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("viewBox", '0 0 450 350')
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// parse the date / time
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

// format the data
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date_facet = parseTime(d.date_facet);
  d.published = +d.published;
});

// order the data
data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a["date_facet"] - b["date_facet"];
})


// Extend the domain by 12 hours on each side to account for the bar widths
var xDomain = d3.extent(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.date_facet;
}));
// Deep copy the date objects to make sure you can make safe modifications
xDomain = [new Date(xDomain[0]), new Date(xDomain[1])];
xDomain[0].setHours(xDomain[0].getHours() - 12);
xDomain[1].setHours(xDomain[1].getHours() + 12);

// X axis
var x = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([0, width])
  .domain(xDomain);

var xDomainInDays = (x.domain()[1] - x.domain()[0]) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
var xBarWidth = width / xDomainInDays;
var padding = 0.2;

// Y axis
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0])
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return Math.max(d.published);
  }) + 4]);

// Add X axis, ticks and labels
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis-minor")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
    .ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1))
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b")))
  .selectAll("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("dx", "-.8em")
  .attr("dy", ".15em")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-45)");


svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

// Bars
svg.selectAll("mybar")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    // Get the x coordinate
    // Then shift by half of xBarWidth so the middle of the bar is at the tick
    // Then apply half of the padding (other half at the other side)
    return x(d.date_facet) - (xBarWidth / 2) + (padding / 2) * xBarWidth;
  })
  // Make the bar "padding * xBarWidth" thinner so it applies the padding correctly
  .attr("width", xBarWidth - padding * xBarWidth)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.published);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.published);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph"></div>
```

This does come with some complications.

- You need to calculate the bar width yourself. I did this by checking the size of the domain and the size of the range, so I found the width available to each bar that way;
- The tick will be at the left edge of each bar. If you want to centre it (which I did here), you need to play with padding and centre the bar on the tick;
- Now, the bar will exceed the axis by a bit. You can make the domain 12 hours larger in both directions, this solves the issue.